# What is the difference between Schelling and Hegel's philosophies

Tags: hegel, idealism, german-philosophy, schelling

Two of the biggest German Idealism movement, Schelling and Hegel, have a very similar line of thought. I was wondering a simple question (with probably a long and complex question): What is the difference between Schelling's System of Transcendental Idealism and Hegel's Philosophy of Spirit(/Mind)? (In both systematic and theoretic perspectives).

Comment: That's a really big question. Can you narrow it?

Comment: @virmaior I know, and to be honest, I'd like a big answer, but a referral will do just fine. Although, if I'm narrowing it, my main interest is the fact that I see a lot of philosophers saying that Hegel is a much larger system than Schelling’s, but they're both practically the same. And I'd like to know if it's true (the systems are the ones I've referred in the question - Transcendental Idealism and Philosophy of Spirit).

Comment: See if you can find "The Young Hegel" PDF (see part III and IV)  floating around by G. Lukacs. It's in English, and probably in other languages too. It was is not "the" answer to your question, but one source you may wish to consult. Also Lukac's writing on existentialism at Marxist.org. This will give you the big moves and themes (at least according to Lukacs).

Comment: @Gordon thank you, I'll take a look. "The Young Hegel" compares the two somewhat? Edit: holly shit this is as long as History of the Spirit lol

Comment: Just read parts III and IV then. :)

Comment: @Gordon haha I surely will.